# Find and replace all links in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to find and replace in all db fields which contains a link in my database?how is that possible?

I have more tables but i don't know which tables :),i need to search programmatically.

I need to a method,example,GetContainsaLink(dbname) it should returns me tables and which field contains a link,

I have already a dictionary map old and new link for changing.

Example:

old link in a db field :images/123/789/picture/9D/10006685.jpg
new link in a db field :images/345/8001/picture/9D/10006685.jpg

Comment: What are the rules for changing a link? Do you have a list of old vs new?

Comment: One example. What would `images/645/24/picture/4E/13422432.jpg` change to?

Comment: example new image link is the images/756/43/picture/9B/13422233.jpg but i have already a dictonoary map old and new link for changing,its not a problem,problem is find them in database..

Comment: OK. Now we know you have a dictionary. We didn't know that until now. Thanks for sharing. Now, about all these tables - you have these fields in more than one table?

Comment: yes more tables but i dont know which tables :),i need to search programaticly.

Comment: Then _edit_ the question and add all of this detail to it. Are you expecting people to guess?

Comment: i need to a method,example,GetContainsaLink(dbname) it should returns me  tables and which field contains a link.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do in as much detail as possible. People are not mind readers.

Comment: actualy i was not sure my problem i was very confisued,when you asked me your questions my mind becomed so clear :)

Comment: acctulay i think i have to use regex pattern for searching a contains link db field,but how i can treewalk all tables and table fileds?

Answer (score 0):

Dump your from -> to mapping into a new table, and perform updates such as the below:

```
UPDATE MLT
SET link = LM.newlink
FROM mylinktable MLT
INNER JOIN linkmap LM
ON LM.oldlink = MLT.link
```

...to find which fields need updating - now that requires some knowledge of the data you're storing.  A query such as `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%link%'` may be useful here.

Comment: @tobias - in your question you say "db field". You need to explain more. Why not edit your question and add that you need to change this field in multiple tables, as it appears in many of them.

Comment: sorry,i just have changed it.